# rolling joins data.table in R

Tags: r, join, time-series, data.table

I am trying to understand a little more about the way rolling joins work and am having some confusion, I was hoping somebody could clarify this for me.  To take a concrete example:

```
dt1 <- data.table(id=rep(1:5, 10), t=1:50, val1=1:50, key="id,t")
dt2 <- data.table(id=rep(1:5, 2), t=1:10, val2=1:10, key="id,t")
```

I expected this to produce a long `data.table` where the values in `dt2` are rolled:

```
dt1[dt2,roll=TRUE]
```

Instead, the correct way to do this seems to be:

```
dt2[dt1,roll=TRUE]
```

Could someone explain to me more about how joining in `data.table` works as I am clearly not understanding it correctly.  I thought that `dt1[dt2,roll=TRUE]` corresponded to the sql equivalent of `select * from dt1 right join dt2 on (dt1.id = dt2.id and dt1.t = dt2.t)`, except with the added functionality locf.

Additionally the documentation says:

```
X[Y] is a join, looking up X's rows using Y (or Y's key if it has one) 
as an index.
```

This makes it seem that only things in X should be returned an the join being done is an inner join, not outer.  What about in the case when `roll=T` but that particular `id` does not exist in `dt1`? Playing around a bit more I can't understand what value is being placed into the column.

Comment: I've written a blog post describing how rolling joins work here http://gormanalysis.com/r-data-table-rolling-joins/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That quote from the documentation appears to be from FAQ 1.12 *What is the difference between X[Y] and merge(X,Y)*.  Did you find the following in `?data.table` and does it help?

> `roll` Applies to the last join column, generally a date but can be any
>   ordered variable, irregular and including gaps. If roll=TRUE and i's
>   row matches to all but the last x join column, and its value in the
>   last i join column falls in a gap (including after the last
>   observation in x for that group), then the prevailing value in x is
>   rolled forward. This operation is particularly fast using a modified
>   binary search. The operation is also known as last observation carried
>   forward (LOCF). Usually, there should be no duplicates in x's key, the
>   last key column is a date (or time, or datetime) and all the columns
>   of x's key are joined to. A common idiom is to select a
>   contemporaneous regular time series (dts) across a set of identifiers
>   (ids): DT[CJ(ids,dts),roll=TRUE] where DT has a 2-column key (id,date)
>   and CJ stands for cross join.

> `rolltolast` Like roll but the data is not rolled forward past the last
>   observation within each group defined by the join columns. The value
>   of i must fall in a gap in x but not after the end of the data, for
>   that group defined by all but the last join column. roll and
>   rolltolast may not both be TRUE.

In terms of left/right analogies to SQL joins, I prefer to think about that in the context of FAQ 2.14 *Can you explain further why data.table is inspired by A[B] syntax
in base*.  That's quite a long answer so I won't paste it here.

Comment: i did not see that, thank you for posting. what confuses me is that x[y] returns rows that are in y but not in x? this doesn't seem like an equi-join... in particular x[y] and merge(x, y, all.y=TRUE) seem to be the same no?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. `nomatch` is by default `NA`, so that's an outer join by default. Set 'nomatch' to 0 for inner join. The term equi-join is meant to convey that `=` occurs in the (analogous) where clause, as opposed to `roll` which is analogous to `<=`. _Equi_ join isn't analogous to _innner_ join.

Comment: Also, to confuse you further, seach `?data.table` for _by without by_. Since `mult` is `"all"` by default, what's really happening in `X[Y]` is grouping, and it's putting the join columns from Y into the result (which is why you think it's returning rows from Y). Once you understand that, move on to `join inherited scope`.

Comment: Have you seen and followed the tip at the top of `?data.table` to run `example(data.table)` and work through the examples at the prompt?

Comment: i have, yes, but i was still baffled unfortunately. i started coming up with my own examples to try to understand the logic but there seemed to be contradictory things going on so i couldn't figure out what was happening.  this makes it a bit clearer although i might have more questions down the line.

Comment: `rolltolast` is being replaced by `rollends` in v1.9.6.  :
`  'rolltolast' has been marked 'deprecated' in ?data.table since v1.8.8 on CRAN 3 Mar 2013, see NEWS. Please change to the more flexible 'rollends' instead. 'rolltolast' will be removed in the next version.`

Comment: @swihart +1 thanks. Any chance you could edit the answer directly would be faster.