# How to perform a inner roll join with data table?

Tags: r, data.table

Take for example

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
df_test_1 <- 
    data.table(time = c(seq(20, 40, by = 5))) %>%
    mutate(values = -time) %>%
    setkey(time)

df_test_2 <-
    data.table(time = c(15, 20, 26, 28)) %>%
    mutate(orig_time = time) %>%
    setkey(time)
```

The roll join `df_test_2[df_test_1, roll = -Inf]` produces:

```
   time orig_time values
1:   20        20    -20
2:   25        26    -25
3:   30        NA    -30
4:   35        NA    -35
5:   40        NA    -40
```

The last three rows contain `NA`s in the `orig_time` column because there are no records in `df_test_2` with time greater than or equal to 30.

I would like to produce the 'inner' version of the above join, that is, do not output rows where there is no time matched, e.g.:

```
   time orig_time values
1:   20        20    -20
2:   25        26    -25
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To replicate an inner join you can use the `nomatch` argument.

`df_test_2[df_test_1, roll = -Inf, nomatch=0]`

See also:

[rolling joins data.table in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12030932/3846570)

[R - Data.Table Rolling Joins](http://gormanalysis.com/r-data-table-rolling-joins/)