# How to perform a join based on intervals with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have a data frame containing two columns: a grouping variable and a interval period over which the grouping variable holds. I have another data frame with a date column and a value column. How can I join these two tables together somewhat efficiently with dplyr+tidyverse functions?

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
ty <- data_frame(date = mdy(paste(1, 1 + seq(20), 2017, sep = "/")), 
                 y = c(rnorm(7), rnorm(7, mean = 2), rnorm(6, mean = -1)))
gy <- data_frame(period = interval(mdy(c("01/01/2017", "01/08/2017", "01/15/2017")), 
                                   mdy(c("01/07/2017", "01/14/2017", "01/20/2017"))), 
                          batch = c(1, 2, 3))
```

I want to build the table that is equivalent to:

```
ty %>% mutate(batch = c(rep(1, 7), rep(2, 7), rep(3, 6)))
```

Ideally, this should work reasonably quickly on data sets of up to 1,000,000 rows. Better still if it works on 100,000,000 :).

Comment: this does not answer your question (`dplyr`), but as a comment -- you should check out [rolling joins in `data.table`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030932/rolling-joins-data-table-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>How about:</del>

```
ty %>% 
  mutate(batch = case_when(
  ty$date %within% gy$period[1] ~gy$batch[1],
  ty$date %within% gy$period[2] ~gy$batch[2],
  ty$date %within% gy$period[3] ~gy$batch[3]))
```

<del>You would obviously need to define the case_when intervals. How many have you got? I've used `cat` and `paste0` with good effect for that in the past.</del>

**Edited to reflect OP's comments.** This should take care of the NSE and would allow the generation of the case_when intervals programatically:

```
ty %>%
  mutate(batch = eval(parse(text = paste0("case_when(",
                                      paste(
                                        paste0(
                                          "ty$date %within% gy$period[",
                                          seq_along(gy$period),
                                          "] ~gy$batch[",
                                          seq_along(gy$period),
                                          "]"
                                        ),
                                        collapse = ", "
                                      ), ")"))))
```

Comment: This is a good idea for a relatively small number of batches. I have ~ 10,000, though. With all the NSE, I worry that this wouldn't work with paste and eval, but maybe I'm wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could come up with so far:

```
ty$batch <- unlist(lapply(ty$date, function(d) gy$batch[which(d %within% gy$period)]), recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE)
```

But it doesn't seem very fast.